# Group Rows by ID and Create an Array Field - GoogleSQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking to convert multiple rows in a database into one single array in GoogleSQL. I've had no luck so far getting this to work.

My Dataset has 2 fields, an ID & Value. I've attached below the current and required output for the query

Any response would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select id, array_agg(value) value
from `project.dataset.table`
group by id
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]